# How to start a C program and send input from a file using the "gnome-terminal" command?

Tags: c, linux, unix, gnome-terminal

To clarify the question: I need to open a terminal window, execute a C program (which takes input from a file) and save its output to a file.

I know that if I do "./program < input.txt > output.txt", I'll get what I want.

For some reason, if I do "gnome-terminal -e ./program < input.txt > output.txt", the program opens on a different terminal window, but doesn't take the input from input.txt nor saves the output to the output.txt file.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because you are redirecting the input and the output of the current terminal session (i.e. that from which `program` is executed).

Comment: @GiuseppePes So how do I redirect input and output of the other session (the one which executes ./program)?

I already tried gnome-terminal -e "./program < input.txt > output.txt"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need bash to redirect input and output in new gnome terminal.

```
    gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c "./program < input.txt > output.txt"'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `gnome-terminal -e "./program < input.txt > output.txt"`